# Java TimeTask continue program after cancel

Tags: java, repeat

I am trying to simulate a cow getting hungry in Java, and for that I want it to lose 'hunger points' every x seconds and starve if the hunger points get to zero. I tried using TimeTask to archive this, and in particular I used the following code:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class CowGame {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          class cow {
              String name = "unnamed";
              int hunger = 60;
              
              void setName(String name) {
                      this.name = name;
              }
              void setHunger(int hunger) {
                this.hunger = hunger;
              }
          }
          
          cow Betti = new cow();
          Betti.setName("Betti");
          Betti.setHunger(10);
          
          Timer monitorHunger = new Timer();
          MyTimerTask getHungry = new MyTimerTask1(Betti.name,Betti.hunger);
          monitorHunger.schedule(getHungry, 0, 500);
          System.out.println("test");
          
      }
}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
      int param;
      String name;
      public MyTimerTask(String name, int param) {
            this.param = param;
            this.name = name;
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
            System.out.println(param); 
            if (param == 0) {
                  System.out.println(name + " starved...");
                  cancel();
            }
            else {
                  param --;
            }
      }
}
```

The problem is that the cancel method does not seem to work as I would expect, as the program does not end after the hunger points have fallen to zero, but it just stays in a state of doing nothing. In particular, the program does not print out 'test' after thee TimeTask has stopped. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The Timer and TimerTask classes were supplanted years ago by the executor service framework and `Runnable`/`Callable` tasks. This has been covered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BasilBourque Is there any way you could show me how that would look like in my example? I tried looking up how Runnables work, but I was not able to implement that in my case...